# How to find click position of the child in app widget (Remoteviews).?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have faced this problem. I have one Parent Linear Layout that is containing three child view in horizontally view. When click on the particular child. Let me know position of the clicked child view. That is problem in Remoteviews because it is not implement onclick event.

This is main xml.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llwidgetlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="1dp" >
     </LinearLayout>
```

This layout contains three child through dynamically

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    remoteViews.removeAllViews(R.id.llwidgetlist);
                for(int position=0;position<4;position++){
                    RemoteViews nestedView = widgetGallery.getWidgetHolder(position);
                    remoteViews.addView(R.id.llwidgetlist, nestedView);
                }
```

child.xml

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ll_widgetplaceholder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#787878"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

This child code..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.indianexpress.android.StoryDescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("storylist",storyLists);
                intent.putExtra("position",?);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                itemViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ll_widgetplaceholder, pendingIntent);
```

Let me know clicked position of the child .Please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to implement `View.OnTouchListener` and override method `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev)` in child view

Comment: thank you.Let me know child touch position.

Answer (score 1):

maybe what you want to do is call nestedView.setOnClickPendingIntent, so that the intent is attached to one individual remoteview child